# $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 -n -1}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like hint as to how we might solve this $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 -n -1}{n!}$. Convergence is easy to show via the ratio test.  I have tried computing the sequence of partial sums, separating into a sum of "simpler" series. For example, I separate this into $$\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{n^2 -n}{n!}-\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{1}{n!}$$

or $$\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{1}{(n-2)!}-\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{1}{n!}$$

I thought about removing some terms from the right sum, so I could use the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=e$. Can I do so? Will this method lead anywhere? I don't really know what else to do here.

Comment: Yes that method will work. Write out the first few terms of your sum and see what that suggests.

Comment: Your second expression shows that the summation is a [telescoping sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028183/sum-n-2-infty-fracn2-n-1n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your difference of two sums is$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}\frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=2}^m\frac{1}{k!}=2-\frac{1}{(m-1)!}-\frac{1}{m!}.$$I'm sure you can find the $m\to\infty$ limit.